# Typescript: specify function return type when declaring a property of type "Function"

Tags: typescript, properties

In this code:

```
export class FormElement {
    ...
    min?: number | Function;
    step?: number | Function;
    ...
}
```

How can I specify that if I set a function in `min` or `step` it should return a number? 
Is it even necessary to specify that it can be a function?

Comment: If it's a function, how do you plan to call it?  Is it a zero-argument function or will it take a parameter?

Comment: It can be any function returning a number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type signature for a function which takes an unspecified number of arguments and returns a number is

```
(...args: any) => number;
```

You can give it a name and use it like this:

```
type FunctionReturningNumber = (...args: any) => number;

export class FormElement {
    min?: number | FunctionReturningNumber;
    step?: number | FunctionReturningNumber;
}

const formElement = new FormElement();
formElement.min = 3; // okay
formElement.min = () => 3; // okay
formElement.min = (x: string, y: number, z: boolean) => 3; // okay
formElement.min = () => "whoopsie"; // error! string is not number
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMbAJYHsECULDgJwVQQHMA5OAWwCMJ8oBeKACgDp2BDfEgZwC4oHBCACUjAHxQEVWvgDcAWABQyiAA8w6fMChIANhx49YWygFE9EShAQ6A3sqhOolYgH4B0mnSgAfWIgoGNi4BESkFN7yjs48wBBgHlIyPv7wyGiYOHiExOQp0UoAvsrKSJhxUABmphZWNjpMCBAA7ib45pbWtswiiko1HXXdwKyuCIxQAMxyUAD0c1DoANYcIMqDnfW2Y8STvRLTswtLq+sDtV0NuxNMzGoCcfh5ADRQIJ4FbwBeAtTo6EsQjEDEkM3mixWaw2l22o3G+xBkgARC0ABYAsA8VAQZHHRZ0fBaACEUCeeSgqGMCHQOi8slKKiUQA)